# HBase Scan api with multiple filtering conditions

Tags: java, hbase

I am very new to HBase api and seeing some strange results when doing the following.

We are trying to scan based on multiple filters. I want to pass all the filter conditions.  I am using the below code.

```
FilterList filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
Filter pageFilter = new PageFilter(5000);
filterList.addFilter(pageFilter);
SingleColumnValueFilter filterOne = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes(COLUMN_FAMILY),
                Bytes.toBytes(COLUMN_NAME1), CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(value1));
filterList.addFilter(filterOne);
SingleColumnValueFilter filterTwo = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes(COLUMN_FAMILY),
                Bytes.toBytes(COLUMN_NAME2), CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(value2));
filterList.addFilter(filterOne);
filterList.addFilter(filterTwo);

//Scan
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setFilter(filterList);
Result result;
try {
            scanner = hTable.getScanner(scan);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
while ((result = scanner.next()) != null) {
  //print the result.
}
//If I am adding multiple SingleColumnValueFilter and I am not doing a addCoulmn() to the scan I am not getting any result even though there are records.

//If I am adding a column to scan then I am seeing results. Initially the result set is matching my filter condition but if I am running for bigger hbase data set then I am seeing bad results.

//If I am adding multiple addCoulmn() to my scan then I am not seeing any result
```

I try to look for proper example but none of them seem to be working. Any help in this direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you add filterTwo twice ?

Comment: We don't see where scanner variable is created

Answer (score 0):

You specified a `FilterList` where all the filter must pass (like a "AND" behavior). In the list of filter, you have 2 `SingleColumnValueFilter` which are contradictory : they say that the column `COLUMN_FAMILY:COLUMN_NAME` must be equal to value1 and value2 at the same time. I think that's why you don't get result with the context of your 1st and 3rd comment.

Concerning your 2nd comment, I think you have to keep in mind that the `SingleColumnValueFilter` are applied only if the column exists in the Scan. It may be the explanation of what you see. Check the `setFilterIfMissing(boolean)` method : https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SingleColumnValueFilter.html#setFilterIfMissing-boolean-

Hope it helps

Comment: I have edited my typo. They are two different columns under the same column family. Regarding your second point even if I am adding both the columns in the scan I am not getting the desired result.

Comment: I have modified the code.Still its not producing the desired result.